# Do some file get excluded from being saved in the locate database?

Tags: linux, command, macintosh, locate

Does the locate database not save certain files? Like are there files that excluded from the database by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the `locate` implementation and configuration. On my Ubuntu 16.04, the default configuration skips a few things:

```
$ cat /etc/updatedb.conf
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs ecryptfs fusesmb devtmpfs"
```

This configuration skips bind mounts, the `/tmp`, `/media`, etc. directories, and various filesystems.